# Creating a login function and search function in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been having some difficulty designing a search and login function for my app. I have a list of video's with titles, and I need to create a search function (much like the youtube app) to search through the list. What would be the best way to go about doing this? Search the video's before they get fetched, and display the results, or search through the array after it's been fetched.

I also need to connect with an apache server to login in my app, and display unique content.

I haven't been able to find any samples on the matter.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Clarification: By "fetch" do you mean from a server or from Core Data? Are you asking whether to send a search to the server and or to download a list of available files and search it locally? Remember, there are a vast number of search requirements and we need to have some idea of what type of search you want to do and where.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was late. I meant from the server. I only want to search based on the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too vague.  There are many paths that you can take.  Your videos can be searchable on your remote apache server, or your iOS app can download the list of videos and search locally.  This depends on the number of videos.

Best way is to have a table view with a list, and a search field on top.  To get to this table view, the iOS app asks the user to login.  If it's valid, then it shows the table/search views.

Comment: That's exactly what I asked. I figured that the search on the apache server was the better method, but I dont have experience with either. 

By the way, the search and login function were supposed to be apart. from eachother, but I didn't want to create a bunch of topics.